# Maximizing a window taking a long time on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, maximized

On my Ubuntu 12.04 maximizing a window - for example terminal - is taking a long time (5+ seconds). Other applications, such as an empathy chat window, are taking up to 2 seconds to maximize.

I have an nvidia card in the laptop, and things were fine before upgrading ubuntu from 10.10 to 12.04. Now there are no more wobbly windows and it takes a while to maximize a window.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem when using 12.04 with my Nvidia Quadro NVS 295. Installing the "post-release" driver didn't work for me.

However disabling window animations in Compiz Settings Manager seemed to fix the problem *(although you miss out on some pretty effects).

I installed Compiz Settings Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then ran it from Unity dash and de-selected "Animations" under the "Effects" section.

Answer (score 1):

On my NVidia Quadro NVS 140M, i experienced the same behavior with the regular proprietary drivers. The problem went away when I upgraded to the "post-release" NVidia driver.